# dynamic fnder findAllBy getting null value from join table in many to many relationship using grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 3 domain as Subscriber, Role and a join table as SubscriberRole for many to many relationship. Dynamic finder findAllBy getting null value from SubscriberRole domain.

**Subscriber.groovy**:

```
class Subscriber extends PartyRole{

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    List<Contact> contacts =  new ArrayList<Contact>();

    static belongsTo = [ customer: Customer]
    static hasMany = [seats: Seat, ownedEnquiries: Enquiry,enquiresSharedWith: SharedEnquiry, enquiriesSharedBy: SharedEnquiry ,
    managedTeams: Team , memberships: Membership, contacts: Contact , sharedByContacts: SharedContact, sharedWithContacts: SharedContact,
    vContacts: VContact, partOf: VContact,  sharedbyVContacts: SharedVcontact, sharedWithVcontacts: SharedVcontact, tokens : Token,
    notifications: Notification, discussions: Discussion]
    static mappedBy = [ managedTeams : "manager" , enquiresSharedWith: "sharedWith" , enquiriesSharedBy: "sharedBy"  ,
                                                   sharedByContacts : "sharedBy" , sharedWithContacts : "sharedWith" ,
                                                   vContacts: "forSubscriber"  ,  partOf :"ofContact",
                                                   sharedbyVContacts: "sharedby" , sharedWithVcontacts :"sharedWith"
                                                    ]

    StatusEnum status
    static constraints = {

        contacts nullable: true
        notifications nullable : true

    }


    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        SubscriberRole.findAllBySubscriber(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    public Subscriber(){
        contacts = LazyList.decorate(contacts,  FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Contact.class))
    }




}
```

**SubscriberRole.groovy:Domain**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class SubscriberRole implements Serializable {

    Subscriber subscriber
    Role role
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof SubscriberRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.subscriber?.id == subscriber?.id &&
            other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (subscriber) builder.append(subscriber.id)
        if (role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static SubscriberRole get(long subscriberId, long roleId) {
        find 'from SubscriberRole where subscriber.id=:subscriberId and role.id=:roleId',
            [subscriberId: subscriberId, roleId: roleId]
    }

    static SubscriberRole create(Subscriber subscriber, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        new SubscriberRole(subscriber: subscriber, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(Subscriber subscriber, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        SubscriberRole instance = SubscriberRole.findBySubscriberAndRole(subscriber, role)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(Subscriber subscriber) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM SubscriberRole WHERE subscriber=:subscriber', [subscriber: subscriber]
    }

    static void removeAll(Role role) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM SubscriberRole WHERE role=:role', [role: role]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'subscriber']
        version false
    }
}
```

**Role.groovy domain**:

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

class Role {

    String authority
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }


    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see from image, subscriber_role has 3 entries but when I try with findAllBySubscriber, it gives me null value. Any idea,why this is happening?

**Problem:**. When I fetch data from SubscriberRole table using**

```
Subscriber subscriber = Subscriber.get(params.id) 
def subscriberRole = SubscriberRole.findAllBySubscriber(subscriber)
```

I am getting NULL [com.vproc.member.SubscriberRole : null] though SubscriberRole table has entries in db.
Is there anything wrong with above dynamic finder.

Comment: If you are getting results as [com.vproc.member.SubscriberRole : null], it shows you are getting list of size 1. So something may be wrong with you toString().

Comment: hi @swapy what I can do here? Any suggestions

Comment: hi @swapy If I do SubscriberRole.list(), it gives me [com.vproc.member.SubscriberRole : null] but 3 times.Why this is happening?

Comment: thts right because your SubscriberRole has three entries in it. But those three are not same in internal structre. They sure referring to Subscriber & Role as per you table

Comment: hi @swapy , I think this may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's showing you in that format ([com.vproc.member.SubscriberRole : null]). that null must be because you have composite key on SubscriberRole.

But you are getting proper data as needed.

For representation you could add nice toString to your SubscriberRole, like,

```
public String toString()
{
    return "${subscriber} :: ${role}"
}
```

Comment: hi @swapy, where should I add these line. In SubscriberRole domain or somewhere else?

Comment: hi @swapy , SubscriberRole instance = SubscriberRole.findBySubscriberAndRole(subscriber, role) this should work?

Comment: yes this should work. Add in SubscriberRole. Basically this should return any string, help you identify SubscriberRole

Comment: hi @swapy, I tried with SubscriberRole instance = SubscriberRole.findBySubscriberAndRole(subscriber, role), I got values: [com.vproc.member.PartyRole : 3, []] , now I can get Subscriber which is 3 but now role is emapty. how to get subscriber role here.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?